# Combine two codes into one - check if url exist / login

Tags: javascript

I have written a code to relink depending on the user input (token).
For example: if the user inserts 1234, and presses enter or presses the button login. The website will redirect to: example.com/login/1234.

Now I want to combine it with a url check. So if the url doesn't exist, they receive a message that the token is not valid, instead of a 404 error.

This is the valid code for the login:

```
var input = document.getElementById("token");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("loginenter").click();
    }
});

function changeQuery(){
    var input_query = document.getElementById('token').value;
    window.parent.location = "https://www.example.com/login/" + input_query;
}
```

And this is the check for a not valid of broken URL:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var status;
var statusText;
request.open("GET", URL, true);
request.send();
request.onload = function(){
    status = request.status;
    statusText = request.statusText;
}

if (status == 200) {
    //if(statusText == OK)
    window.parent.location = "https://www.example.com/login/" + input_query;
} else {
   console.log("not valid");
}
```

Combined I have this:

```
var input = document.getElementById("token");

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var status;
var statusText;
request.open("GET", URL, true);
request.send();
request.onload = function(){
    status = request.status;
    statusText = request.statusText;
}
if(status == 200) {
    //if(statusText == OK)
    window.parent.location = "https://www.example.com/login/" + input_query;
} else {
   console.log("not valid");
}

input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("loginenter").click();
    }
});

function changeQuery(){
    var input_query = document.getElementById('token').value;

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var status;
    var statusText;
    request.open("GET", URL, true);
    request.send();
    request.onload = function(){
        status = request.status;
        statusText = request.statusText;
    }
    if(status == 200) {
        //if(statusText == OK)
        window.parent.location = "https://www.example.com/login/" +      
input_query;
    } else {
        console.log("not valid");
    }
```

I would like it to return a message "that the token is not valid" but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You are using `request.onload` as a callback but checking the status from outside. Try to check your status inside `onload` function.

Comment: It seems that you have your request code duplicated. When/where is the `changeQuery` function called?